# Script de php mail() dejo de funcionar

Tags: php

Tengo un script de php que envia un mail, funcionando hace meses que dejo de funcionar. Aisle el script de envio de mail a lo minimo en un archivo aparte, y tampoco se envia. Este es el codigo:

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "contacto@midominio.com.ar";
$to = "ariel@mimail.com";
$subject = "Checking PHP mail";
$message = "PHP mail works just fine";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$enviado = mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
if($enviado){
    echo "The email message was sent.";
}
```

chequee en mi panel del proveedor de hosting que el sendmail este activado. como se ve en el codigo tengo el error reporting encendido y sin embargo no se envia ni tampoco me imprime ningun error.

Comment: Cuando dices que no imprime ningún error, lo dices porque no muestra nada en pantalla? Revisaste los logs del servidor? Lo otro, encierra tu envío en un [try/catch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) para atrapar cualquier excepción que necesites revisar... y revisa en los logs de su servidor SMTP para validar que está procesando lo que recibe. Recuerda que eso es sólo una cola que le dice a tu código "Recibido" y es el servidor SMTP el que realmente procesa el envío.

Comment: ¿Revisaste la carpeta SPAM de `ariel@mimail.com`? Puede que los mensajes estén en esa carpeta. ¿El mensaje `The email message was sent.` se imprime en pantalla o no?

Comment: no, no se imprime el mensaje, el mail no se envia, y tampoco imprime errores en pantalla, tenia entendido que las primeras dos lineas eran para eso. de todas formas me fije y no esta en spam, pero no se envia. como reviso mis logs del servidor SMTP?

Comment: Intenta capturar un mensaje: **`if ($enviado) {
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
} else  { var_dump(error_get_last()); }`**